# Performing SQL queries taking inputs from Excel Table in VBA Macro

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I would like to take inputs from a table in Excel to perform SQL query and output it to a location in the Excel sheet.

Macro:

```
Sub SQL(Dim strSQL as String)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Debug.Print rs.GetString

End Sub
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  e.`isin`,
  b.*
FROM
  `risk_reference`.`basket_debt` AS b
  JOIN `risk_reference`.`etp` AS e
    ON IF(
      e.`parentid_override` > 0,
      e.`parentid_override`,
      e.`parentid`
    ) = b.`parentid`
    AND e.`isin` = ?
    AND e.`date_out` IS NULL
WHERE b.`processing_date` IN
  (SELECT
    MAX(processing_date)
  FROM
    `risk_reference`.`basket_debt`)
GROUP BY e.`isin`, b.`pk_id`
```

The ? in the SQL query is where I need a list of items to go in based on a table in Excel.

Should i do SQL query item by item or can i do it in one shot? If so, how do i do it? If I do line by line, how do I get to output one location in the excel?

Need some advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variant of sql supports it, use IN and loop through cells to buiold the list

```
strsql = "SELECT e.`isin`, b.* FROM `risk_reference`.`basket_debt` AS b JOIN "
strsql = strsql & "`risk_reference`.`etp` AS e ON IF( e.`parentid_override` > 0, "
strsql = strsql & "e.`parentid_override`, e.`parentid`) = b.`parentid`"
strsql = strsql & "AND e.`isin` IN ("
dim c as range
for each c in range("your range here")
   strsql = strsql & "'" & c.text & "',"
next c
strsql = strsql & ") "
strsql = strsql & "AND e.`date_out` IS NULL WHERE b.`processing_date` IN "
strsql = strsql & "(SELECT MAX(processing_date) FROM `risk_reference`.`basket_debt`) "
strsql = strsql & "GROUP BY e.`isin`, b.`pk_id`"
```